# VSCode extension - Detect if current project is nodejs or python based

Tags: vscode-extensions

Is there a way to programmatically determine whether the current opened workspace in VSCode is a NodeJS project or a python based project?

In my extension I would like to use some logic, like so...

```js
const projectContext = determineProjectType();
if (projectContext === "python") {
  vscode.window.showInformationMessage("pyhton based project");
  // do something python specific
} else if (projectContext === "nodejs") {
  vscode.window.showInformationMessage("project is nodejs");
  // do something nodejs specific
}
```

Comment: No, that's not possible. VSCode itself (without any extension) is just a code editor, so you literally just open a folder in it, especially when this folder contains both Python and NodeJS file (rather common in Linux world). You can only define such logic at file level, such as "this folder has Python files" and "this folder has NodeJS files".

Comment: ok, yeah that makes sense. thanks